# Is there any way to hide or move the "Maximum number of concurent builds reached" window?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, incredibuild

When I build multiple projects with IncrediBuild, I get this popup:

[image]

This is OK, I don't want to build them concurrently anyway. The problem is, the popup is in the middle of the screen, set as topmost and I cannot move it or hide it.

Is there a setting to change this IncrediBuild behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

just tick off this option from agent settings.

Agents settings->>Initiator-->Multiple Builds-->Limit number of concurrent builds

Comment: I do not want to change that number, the builds need to happen in series. I just want to make the window less annoying.